Add network to an existing GCP cloud dns zone via terraform
I am looking at terraform documentation, but could not find resource that can help add new networks to existing Cloud DNS zone, similar to AWS aws_route53_zone_association.
I tried to use google_dns_managed_zone to add associate a new network, it fails with resource 'entity.managedZone' already exists.
How can this be achieved?

Edit your question and show what you tried (the actual Terraform) and details on the network configuration. As written, your question does not have the details to provide a fact based answer.

It is literally the second example in the documentation:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/dns_managed_zone#example-usage---dns-managed-zone-private
If you want to update the existing one, you will need to import it into your state using
import {
  id = "projects/{{project}}/managedZones/{{name}}"
  to = google_dns_managed_zone.default
}


I am looking for the same behavior as aws_route53_zone_association, where the association of vpc's can be done without deleting the existing zone nor need to import.
It looks in gcp it is not possible via terraform yet.

You seem to have created the original zone manually or via gcloud or via Terraform and then lost the state. State import is not the same as zone import. You are just missing the zone in the state...

my requirement is there is already a DNS zone created manually. Is there any terraform resource that can be used to add network to already created DNS zone. It is possible in AWS to associate a vpc to existing hosted zone (it does not require any state, pass the existing zone id and it helps associate). But from gcp, I see it is possible via rest and gcloud cli, but not via terraform.
Hence I am seeking suggestions on is it really a terraform gap or there is some work around that can help associate network to existing zone

If you add the import block as shown, the plan will show you that the existing zone's network config would be updated. No "already exists" error, no destroy, no create. Just update.
